# Laravel - refreshing posts

Tags: laravel, refresh, posts

I'm trying to make refresh option in my Laravel project. I made a `public function refresh()` in my `CarsController`. The idea is to make `created_at` get current time because my cars are ordered by `orderBy('created_at'. 'desc')->get();`. So this is my `public function refresh()` in my `CarsController`:

```
/**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */

    public function refresh($id)
    {
        $car = Car::find($id);
        $car->created_at = Carbon::now();
        $car->save();
        return redirect('/cars');
    }
```

This is my `Form` in blade:

```
{!!Form::open(['action' => ['CarsController@refresh', $car->id], 'method' => 'PUT'])!!}
   {{Form::hidden('_method', 'PUT')}}
   {{Form::submit('Refresh', ['class' => 'btn btn-success'])}}
{!!Form::close()!!}
```

And this is in my `web.php` route:

```
Route::get('/cars/{id}', 'CarsController@refresh');
```

What I'm doing wrong? Please help. Thanks!

Comment: Do you use `$table->timestamps();` in your migration files?

Comment: @user8555937 Yes I do

Comment: Timestamps are inserted automatically once you create the records using Car::create(); Why do you want to update `created_at` timestamp?

Comment: @user8555937 I wanted to create ```refresh``` option in my project. So when post is refreshed it will be first in posts lists, because my ```public function index()``` is orderd like this ```orderBy('created_at', 'desc')```

Comment: You&#39;ve overloaded the method to PUT, while your route requires GET method :)

Comment: @user8555937 I changed it to ```PUT``` , my route, but nothing happens

Comment: Check the database. `created_at` should be updated with the new timestamp 

Comment: I did but nothing changes :(

Comment: Your route is defined as GET, but in your form it's PUT.

Comment: @AmirAsyraf so what should I do ?

Comment: Change `Route::get('/cars/{id}', 'CarsController@refresh');` to `Route::put('/cars/{id}', 'CarsController@refresh');`

Comment: Personally I would _not_ use `created_at`, that should be done using the `updated_at` field. IMHO, 'created_at' is a field that should only be set when a Post/Article is created, if you want to sort by "latest()" you should use the `updated_at` field or Laravel's `->latest()` method

Answer (score 2):

HTML forms do not support PUT, PATCH or DELETE actions.To solve this, please change your form into this.

```
{!!Form::open(['action' => ['CarsController@refresh', $car->id], 'method' => 'GET'])!!}
   {{Form::submit('Refresh', ['class' => 'btn btn-success'])}}
{!!Form::close()!!}
```

you will remove this line because laravel will expect that your having a put request instead of a get request.

```
{{Form::hidden('_method', 'PUT')}}
```

Comment: I tried this on my blogs posts because my cars posts are some kind of blocked.. I don't know what is happening on cars posts, whatever I do it stay the same, for example I deleted my EDIT button and it is still there...
Anyway I tried this on my blogs post and in url it shows me now when I press Refresh button ```http://localhost:8000/blogs/1?``` maybe wrong route?

Answer (score 0):

For method overloading try the following code:

```
{{Form::hidden('_method', 'GET')}}
```